# How to create an "on-the-fly" mapping table within a SELECT statement in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I'm creating a select statement that combines two tables, `zone` and `output`, 
based on a referenced `device` table and on a mapping of `zone_number` to `output_type_id`. 
The mapping of `zone_number` to `output_type_id` doesn't appear
anywhere in the database, and I would like to create it "on-the-fly" within the select
statement. Below is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE output_type (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE device (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE zone (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    device_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES device(id),
    zone_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE (zone_number)
);

CREATE TABLE output (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    device_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES device(id),
    output_type_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES output_type(id),
    enabled BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And here is some example data:

```
INSERT INTO output_type (id, name) VALUES 
(101, 'Output 1'),
(202, 'Output 2'),
(303, 'Output 3'),
(404, 'Output 4');

INSERT INTO device (id, name) VALUES 
(1, 'Test Device');

INSERT INTO zone (device_id, zone_number) VALUES 
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4);

INSERT INTO output (device_id, output_type_id, enabled) VALUES 
(1, 101, TRUE),
(1, 202, FALSE),
(1, 303, FALSE), 
(1, 404, TRUE);
```

I need to get the associated `enabled` field from the output table for each zone for a given device. 
Each `zone_number` maps to an `output_type_id`. For this example:

```
zone_number | output_type_id
----------------------------
1           | 101
2           | 202
3           | 303 
4           | 404
```

One way to handle the mapping would be to create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE zone_output_type_map (
    zone_number INTEGER,
    output_type_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES output_type(id)
);

INSERT INTO zone_output_type_map (zone_number, output_type_id) VALUES 
(1, 101),
(2, 202),
(3, 303), 
(4, 404);
```

And use the following SQL to get all zones, plus the `enabled` flag, for device 1:

```
SELECT zone.*, output.enabled 
FROM zone
JOIN output 
ON output.device_id = zone.device_id
JOIN zone_output_type_map map
ON map.zone_number = zone.zone_number
AND map.output_type_id = output.output_type_id
AND zone.device_id = 1
```

However, I'm looking for a way to create the mapping of zone nunbers to output
types without creating a new table and without piecing together a bunch of AND/OR
statements. Is there an elegant way to create a mapping between the two fields 
within the select statement? Something like:

```
SELECT zone.*, output.enabled 
FROM zone
JOIN output 
ON output.device_id = zone.device_id
JOIN (
    SELECT (
        1 => 101,
        2 => 202,
        3 => 303,
        4 => 404
    ) (zone_number, output_type_id)
) as map
ON map.zone_number = zone.zone_number
AND map.output_type_id = output.output_type_id
AND zone.device_id = 1
```

Disclaimer: I know that ideally the `enabled` field would exist in the `zone` 
table. However, I don't have control over that piece. I'm just looking for the 
most elegant solution from the application side. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could use a VIEW?

Comment: I would be OK with that, but the underlying mapping would still need to be defined within a select statement (within the view), and that's where it breaks down for me. It seems like there should be a simple way of creating a key/value "hash" that can be used within a select statement to join the two tables.

Comment: Your `output_type` sample data doesn't match your `output. output_type_id`, the first uses 101, 102, 103, and 104 whereas the second uses 101, 202, 303, and 404; hooray for FKs for pointing that out to me :)

Comment: Thanks for the catch @mu! I fixed that in my question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `VALUES` as an inline table and JOIN to it, you just need to give it an alias and column names:

```
join (values (1, 101), (2, 202), (3, 303), (4, 304)) as map(zone_number, output_type_id)
on ...
```

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-values.html):

> `VALUES` can also be used where a sub-`SELECT` might be written, for
>   example in a `FROM` clause:
>
> ```
> SELECT f.*
>   FROM films f, (VALUES('MGM', 'Horror'), ('UA', 'Sci-Fi')) AS t (studio, kind)
>   WHERE f.studio = t.studio AND f.kind = t.kind;
>
> UPDATE employees SET salary = salary * v.increase
>   FROM (VALUES(1, 200000, 1.2), (2, 400000, 1.4)) AS v (depno, target, increase)
>   WHERE employees.depno = v.depno AND employees.sales >= v.target;
> ```

Comment: Beautiful! You can even define aliases for the columns in the result set!

Answer (score 14):

So just to complement the accepted answer, the following code is a valid, **self-contained** Postgresql expression which will evaluate to an 'inline' relation with columns `(zone_number, output_type_id)`:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(VALUES 
  (1, 101), 
  (2, 202), 
  (3, 303), 
  (4, 304)
) as i(zone_number, output_type_id)
```

(The `(VALUES ... AS ...)` part alone will not make a valid expression, which is why I added the `SELECT * FROM`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
JOIN 
(SELECT 1 zone_number, 101 as output_type_id
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 zone_number, 202 as output_type_id
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 zone_number, 303 as output_type_id
) mappings on mappings.zone_number = zone.zone_number
```