# Creating tables on-the-fly

Tags: sql, postgresql

It is often convenient in PosgreSQL to create "tables" on the fly so to refer to them, e.g.

```
with

selected_ids as (
select 1 as id
)

select *
from someTable
where id = (select id from selected_ids)
```

Is it impossible to provide multiple values as `id` this way? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532603/how-to-create-an-on-the-fly-mapping-table-within-a-select-statement-in-postgre) that suggests using `values` for similar problem, but I have problem with translating it to the example below.

I would like to write subqueries such as

```
select 1 as id
union
select 2 as id
union
select 7 as id
```

or

```
select 1 as id, 'dog' as animal
union
select 7 as id, 'cat' as animal
```

in more condensed way, without repeating myself.

Comment: Simply do a UNION ALL?

Comment: @jarlh sure, but declaring 20 values like this would be horrible, I'm looking for more condensed syntax if possible.

Comment: what about using `generate_series()` function to generate ids like [this](http://hastebin.com/dahukitiyo.cs)?.BTW, your question seems a bit unclear for me can you just elaborate the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arguments in the query alias:

```
with selected_ids(id) as (
    values (1), (3), (5)
)
select *
from someTable
where id = any (select id from selected_ids)
```

You can also use `join` instead of a subquery, example:

```
create table some_table (id int, str text);
insert into some_table values
(1, 'alfa'),
(2, 'beta'),
(3, 'gamma');

with selected_ids(id) as (
    values (1), (2)
)
select *
from some_table
join selected_ids
using(id);

 id | str  
----+------
  1 | alfa
  2 | beta
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `id` and `animal` field in WITH like this

```
with selected_ids(id,animal) as (
values (1,'dog'), (2,'cat'), (3,'elephant'),(4,'rat')--,..,.. etc
)
select *
from someTable
where id = any (select id from selected_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use union and IN statement like this:

```
with
selected_ids as (
select 1 as id
union
select 2 as id
union
select 3 as id
....
)
select *
from someTable
where id in (select id from selected_ids)
```

after reviewing [wingedpanther's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150739/creating-tables-on-the-fly/35151275#comment58020438_35150739) idea and looking for it, you can use his idea IF those id's are continuously like this:

```
with
selected_ids as (
SELECT * FROM generate_series(Start,End) --(1,10) for example
)
select *
from someTable
where id in (select id from selected_ids)
```

If they are not continuously , the only way you can do that is by storing those ID's in a different table(maybe you have it already and if not insert it)

And then:

```
select *
from someTable
where id in (select id from OtherTable)
```

Comment: Right, but maybe there is more condense way, so you do not have to repeat `select ? as id union` again and again...

Comment: @Tim updated my answer, this should cover all options

Comment: thanks good points, but it seems my question was not clear so I made it more specific and provided two examples.

Comment: @Tim as I posted here, this is not possible unless the ID's are continuously or if you store those ID's in another table. So this is the best option you got.