# SQL check if multiple exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table Users looks like this:

```
ID    COMPANY_ID    FIRST_NAME
```

```
1     1             John
2     1             Mary
3     2             Ivan
4     1             Arnold
5     3             Sam
```

I need SQL query that may check that pairs exists for `user_id, company_id` of one company and return `[[id, true], [id, false]`.

It mean I want ask if users `[1, 4, 7, 17]` of company `2` exists and receive `[[1, true], [4, true], [7, false], [17, true]]`.

It would be a great if you may suggest how do this with sqlalchemy Core.

Comment: sql or sqlalchemy..pick one.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I don't understand the question can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you would use `left join`.  Assuming `Users` has not duplicates, you would do something like:

```
select t.id, (case when u.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as flag
from (select 1 as id union all
      select 4 union all
      select 7 union all
      select 17
     ) t left join
     users u
     on u.id = t.id and u.company = 2;
```

Comment: You can use a [VALUES expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17533194/479863) in a join so `from (values(1),(4),(7),(17)) t(id) left join ...` should also work. The PostgreSQL tag is probably new though.

Comment: @muistooshort . . . Absolutely.  The Postgres tag was not on the question when I answered.