# perform multiple independent queries in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say we have some `SELECT` query that takes some parameters and returns at most one row

```
SELECT c FROM Foo WHERE a = 'a' AND b = 'b' LIMIT 1;
```

(this query is just an example, and could be arbitrarily complex)

We can put this behind a [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html) that we can then call like

```
CALL get_foo_c('a', 'b');
```

All is great, however say I do not have only one pair of `(a, b)` but I have a list of them, and I want to obtain the list of `c` responses.

```
CALL get_foo_c('a1', 'b1');
CALL get_foo_c('a2', 'b2');
CALL get_foo_c('a3', 'b3');
...
```

receiving back the union of all the queries, in the order they were asked

```
'c1'
'c2'
'c3'
```

The latency to perform a query is quite high, so issuing one query at a time is not feasible.

Obviously, we can just perform the queries in parallel on the clientside. However, I'm looking for alternatives, for reasons that are not relevant to the question, e.g. imagine that the client language is single threaded.

That brings us back to the question: can we perform multiple independent (in the sense that they do not affect each other) queries in postgresql? Perhaps with an api that looks something like

```
CALL get_many_foo_c(('a1','b1'),('a2','b2'),('a3','b3'));
```

receiving back the same response as if the queries were issued one at a time.

I investigated the possibility of using [`FOR LOOP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS) over the input parameters, but I could not see how to make it work, and in any case it would be ideal if postgresql internall were to be able to parallelise each independent query.

Comment: Looks like a cliet-side problem. Create a query queue and and a number of parallel workers within the available other application resources to process the queue.

Comment: Do you want to receive a union of all the data selected? Otherwise what do you expect to get? Without further context this question appears to make little sense...

Comment: Why can't you call functions multiple times? In Unix it like `funtion1 &; funtion2 &; .... `all will be submitted as separate thread.

Comment: @stickybit I've updated the question to be more explicit, I hope that helps.

Comment: @DigvijayS I've updated the question to be explicit that performing parallel queries on the client side is out of scope.

Comment: Hmm, there's the possibility the planner parallelizes parts of queries. Look [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Parallel_Query). So you might want to just build a `UNION ALL` query with a subquery for each of your parameter sets and check the plan for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a *scalar* function instead of a stored procedure.  Then you can call it as:

```
select v.*, get_foo_c(a, b)
from (values ('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a3', 'b3')
     ) v(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

As of PostgreSQL version 12, the parallel query feature is there. You just need to inform the server that your function is parallel-safe, and you can enjoy your single query consume as many CPU cores as you wish.

Recipe follows.

Create the test input data set. In my case it's 100 M rows:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE test1tab (a int, b int);
INSERT INTO test1tab SELECT 1, x FROM generate_series(1,100000000) x;
```

Create your function, mark it `PARALLEL SAFE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1fun(a integer, b integer) RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$
BEGIN
  RETURN 345 * a + b / 2;
END;
$$
PARALLEL SAFE
IMMUTABLE;
```

Inform the server how many parallel threads are you willing to start:

```
SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather TO 4;
```

Run the SELECT on multiple inputs and see your CPUs burning:

```
EXPLAIN /* remove me to light up the fireplace */
SELECT test1fun(a,b)
FROM test1tab;
```

Note: by default, parallel execution will have some threshold, ie. it will not start when there are too few inputs.

It's all configurable and it's all documented - including [parallel query limitations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html), [the whole chapter on parallel queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/parallel-query.html) as well as the [list of GUCs related to asynchronous processing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-ASYNC-BEHAVIOR).

Comment: interesting! The key thing here seems to be to create a temporary table containing the query parameters, and then to use that to issue multiple queries, nice hack! Although now I am still left with the problem of "how do I populate that from the client side?". Presumably this relies on the fact that multiple `INSERT` is possible in a single query. I hope that doesn't end up being an additional cost.

Comment: oh, your UNLOGGED table seems to stick around. I'd need it to be scoped to this one query so it isn't influenced by other queries that are happening at the same time.

Comment: @fommil, I did not try to resolve the issue of performance at all. I just wanted to show you how to enable parallel processing in a single server-side query. It's possible that what you do is a case of premature optimization, and you don't need it at all - depending on the nature of your data and your application.

Comment: that's perfectly fine, the main objective of the question is to be able to reduce multiple queries into one query and you've given good hints in that direction. You might be the one prematurely optimising :-) Rather than using an unlogged table, an ephemeral table like the following will work better for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/45619490/430938

Answer (score 1):

Try CREATE FUNCTION, which is a lot more flexible and integrates better with the SQL execution engine. I would need more specifics, but you can "pass" data to functions much now easily.

If you are trying to optimize the cost of the FUNCTION/PROCEDURE call, then by definition it will be awkward... consider accepting a non-atomic data type, such as array.

If you are trying to optimize the client-server overhead, then load the input data into a table (or temp table) and use SELECT myfunc(a) FROM temp_table; to call myfunc repeatedly. Obviously, temp_table can be a subquery...